# Is it safe to host a video on my website inside a folder within the root folder

Tags: html

I have a video tag with a video linked to it and it runs fine, like this

```
<div class="VideoFrame">
              <video id="Video" src="Videos/AnonomousVideo.mov" controls width="640" height="480"></video>
          </div>
```

is this safe, to just have a folder with a video file in it linked to a video tag. this doesnt give any problems performance wise

Comment: as opposed to what? you could of course upload it to youtube or a similar platform and embed the video player from there.
Loading the video 'locally' from your server will cause you more traffic and at lease some performance penalty, depending on your servers hardware...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes it is safe to have a video uploaded on your server.

**However**

1. This may cause a lot of bandwidth usage.
2. This could slow down your site if multiple people are downloading it at the same time.

**Alternatives**

Why not just use YouTube or Vimeo?